# Make ajax call to send data onclick event in div

Tags: php, ajax

I have a div, which shows `Rate me` section. i.e. Five stars. When the user click on it, the rating value gets prompted.

```
<div class="rateit bigstars" id="rateit99" data-rateit-starwidth="32" data-rateit-starheight="32" onclick="alert($('#rateit99').rateit('value'))">
    </div>
```

In here rather than an alert, I want to make an ajax call, which sends(post data) Rated value to `data.php` file.
How can it be done?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "PLease dont suggest jquery. I have to use ajax" given that jQuery does support ajax.

Comment: @wdosanjos: Ok no issue

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest start from here

Comment: For the jQuery ajax api take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ There are some sample code towards the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what's on your HTML code, but i can understand what you are trying to achieve.

First clean your HTML code to make it easier to read for the purpose.

Here is an example of how you can receive the data and pass it using ajax

```
// Use the id of your trigger element
$('#submit').click(function() {

 // Make your datastring (you can get other values with var a = $('#id').val(); 
 var dataString = 'value1='+ value1 + '&value2=' + value2 ;

    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "data.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data)
  {
          // handle the result 
  } 
});


 });
```

Comment: I'm confused by what it's sending in that script.

Comment: @IGotRoot What exactly do you mean? the `dataString` contains the values being sended to the server, and the `data` from the `success` contains the response that you output from the server.

Comment: I see a lot of things like $.ajax, can you comment the lines in your code block for explanation?

Comment: You can google about **Ajax** on the web, i gave him a solution, but i don't have to teach about the usage of the method.